# Unable to List Item via EBay's Inventory API

Tags: java, json, rest, ebay-api

I'm attempting to list an item on EBay using [EBay's Inventory API](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/inventory_item/methods/createOrReplaceInventoryItem) via the following code (I'm using Apache HTTP Client):

```
public void put() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {
        String url = "https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/inventory_item/83368339";
        String charset = "utf-8";

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPut put = new HttpPut(url);

        // add request header
        put.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <TOKEN>");
        put.addHeader("Content-Language", "en-US");



        String json = "{ \"availability\": { \"pickupAtLocationAvailability\": [ { \"availabilityType\": \"IN_STOCK\", \"fulfillmentTime\": { \"unit\": \"TimeDurationUnitEnum\": \"BUSINESS_DAY\", \"value\": 1 }, \"merchantLocationKey\": \"NJ\", \"quantity\": 1 } ], \"shipToLocationAvailability\": { \"quantity\": 1 } }, \"condition\": \"ConditionEnum : [NEW]\", \"conditionDescription\": \"New condition\","
            + "\"product\": { \"aspects\": \"object\", \"brand\": \"Outlite\", \"description\": \"ADJUSTABLE FOCUS: Intense Spotlight for long range observation can up to 600 feet, Circle Floodlight for large area illumination\", \"imageUrls\": [ \"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71c57aJiDAL._SL1500_.jpg\" ], \"title\": \"Outlite A100 Portable Ultra Bright Handheld LED Flashlight\", \"sku\": \"sku546372817\" }";


        HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);

        System.out.println("Response Code : "
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        System.out.println(result);


    }
```

However I'm encountering the following error:

```
Response Code : 400
{"errors":[{"errorId":2004,"domain":"ACCESS","category":"REQUEST","message":"Invalid request","longMessage":"The request has errors. For help, see the documentation for this API.","parameters":[{"name":"reason","value":"Could not serialize field [availability.pickupAtLocationAvailability.availabilityType]"}]}]}
```

Comment: Get rid of the surrounding parentheses in your payload. It's not valid JSON, and the error message states that.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you need the quotes around the entire payload as well.

Comment: Thanks. I removed quotes / parentheses but now I get new error: `Response Code : 400
{"errors":[{"errorId":2004,"domain":"ACCESS","category":"REQUEST","message":"Invalid request","longMessage":"The request has errors. For help, see the documentation for this API.","parameters":[{"name":"reason","value":"Could not serialize field [availability.pickupAtLocationAvailability.availabilityType]"}]}]}`

Comment: Did you remove the leading and trailing `\"` as well?

Comment: yup, but now the error is `Could not serialize field [availability.pickupAtLocationAvailability.availabilityType]‌​"}]}]` (I updated the original post)

Comment: It's failing to serialize the availabilityType field now. You'll need to provide it with the correct enum value. Try it without the surrounding square brackets around `[IN_STOCK]`. If that doesn't work, you'll need to get the enum value.

Comment: Yeah, almost positive it's the square brackets. Had to dig around a bit for samples, but their enums just use all caps string values: https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/inventory_item/methods/createOrReplaceInventoryItem#_samples

Comment: @wholevinski I removed the square brackets (see latest version in OP) however I am getting the exact same error. I'm also pretty sure that the enum `BUSINESS_DAY` is valid. Also if you could compose all of your comments into one answer I would accept it. I think this is the last part of the puzzle. Thank you!!

Comment: Is the error on availabilityType gone though? Is it just happening on fulfillmentTime.unit?

Comment: yes I believe so the entire error is as follows: `{"errors":[{"errorId":2004,"domain":"ACCESS","category":"REQUEST","message":"Invalid request","longMessage":"The request has errors. For help, see the documentation for this API.","parameters":[{"name":"reason","value":"Could not serialize field [availability.pickupAtLocationAvailability.fulfillmentTime.unit]"}]}]}` so I'm assuming there's no issue with `availabilityType`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments above, there were a few issues:

1. Remove the surrounding parentheses
2. Remove the surrounding quotes around the JSON
3. Enum formatting

After the last comment and confirming that removing the square brackets *might* have cleared up the availabilityType enum issue, here's what I think your final JSON should look like:

```
String json = "{ \"availability\": { \"pickupAtLocationAvailability\": [ { \"availabilityType\": \"IN_STOCK\", \"fulfillmentTime\": { \"unit\": \"BUSINESS_DAY\", \"value\": 1 }, \"merchantLocationKey\": \"NJ\", \"quantity\": 1 } ], \"shipToLocationAvailability\": { \"quantity\": 1 } }, \"condition\": \"NEW\", \"conditionDescription\": \"New condition\","
            + "\"product\": { \"aspects\": \"object\", \"brand\": \"Outlite\", \"description\": \"ADJUSTABLE FOCUS: Intense Spotlight for long range observation can up to 600 feet, Circle Floodlight for large area illumination\", \"imageUrls\": [ \"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71c57aJiDAL._SL1500_.jpg\" ], \"title\": \"Outlite A100 Portable Ultra Bright Handheld LED Flashlight\", \"sku\": \"sku546372817\" }}";
```

Here it is split out into non-Java escapedness:

```
{
    "availability": {
        "pickupAtLocationAvailability": [{
            "availabilityType": "IN_STOCK",
            "fulfillmentTime": {
                "unit": "BUSINESS_DAY",
                "value": 1
            },
            "merchantLocationKey": "NJ",
            "quantity": 1
        }],
        "shipToLocationAvailability": {
            "quantity": 1
        }
    },
    "condition": "NEW",
    "conditionDescription": "New condition",
    "product": {
        "aspects": "object",
        "brand": "Outlite",
        "description": "ADJUSTABLE FOCUS: Intense Spotlight for long range observation can up to 600 feet, Circle Floodlight for large area illumination",
        "imageUrls": ["https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71c57aJiDAL._SL1500_.jpg"],
        "title": "Outlite A100 Portable Ultra Bright Handheld LED Flashlight",
        "sku": "sku546372817"
    }
}
```

I modified the fulfillmentTime.unit and condition enums as well. It also looks like you might've been missing an a closing curly bracket at the end, so I added that as well.

Comment: Works flawlessly. Accepted and up-voted. Thanks for your time and in depth explanation.

Comment: No problem! Good luck and have fun!